# Rxjs - Reset distinctuntilchanged

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

#### Situation

I was wondering if it was possible to reset the `distinctUntilChanged` part 
so that it would reaccept a repeated value.

So my situation is, right now I'm using the function like this (shortened greatly as just an example).

```
    Rx.Observable.fromEvent(textInput, 'keyup')
      .pluck('target','value')
      .filter( (text) => {
          text = text.trim();
          if (!text.length) // empty input field
          {
              this.setState({ list: [] });
          }
          return text.length > 0;
      })
      .debounceTime(300)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
```

So at the very end of this, the results create a series of divs which I can click on, which then changes the value of the input (calls function below).

```
fill_name(name)
{
  $("#company_input").val(name);
  this.setState({ list: [] });
}
```

So if I typed in `a` in the input, then I delete it all with the backspace and retype a, the observable won't call my function.

#### What I want

I want some way for the `fill_name` function to reset the `distinctUntilChanged` part so I can search for `a` again after clicking on my generated divs.

Comment: Move the filtering to *after* the `distinctUntilChanged`. Maybe use `map` and trim before it, but `filter` after it.

Comment: @cartant that seemed to have solved it quite nicely, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have an Observable of generatedDivClicks$:

```
const reset$ = generatedDivClicks$.mapTo('reset');

const input$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(textInput, 'keyup')
  .pluck('target','value')
  .filter( (text) => {
      text = text.trim();
      if (!text.length) // empty input field
      {
          this.setState({ list: [] });
      }
      return text.length > 0;
  })
  .debounceTime(300);

Rx.Observable.merge(reset$, input$)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .filter(x => x !== 'reset')
```